# Facebook Graph API error when posting scheduled post on Business page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook php graph api and I've been trying to post a scheduled post to a business page but with no luck, However, I can successfully post a published status on the same page.

I've read in the FB API, that to post a scheduled status I must set the variable "published" to false when sending the POST request. However when I do this I get the following exception thrown:

```
FacebookApiException
An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
```

The **POST** request looks like this:

```
["\/11111111111111\/feed", "POST", {
    "access_token": "xxxxxx",
    "message": "Test message",
    "picture": "http://working.picture.path.com/pic.jpg",
    "published": false,
    "scheduled_publish_time": 1401406920
}]
```

After this, I've tried remove the "published" variable and got this error:

```
(#100) You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a published post
```

I tried the same code after a few days so this is not facebook's temporary problem... I've tried to set the "published" variable to **int** 0, **bool** false, **string** 'false' and **string** '0'. But I am getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem....

The problem was caused by the "picture" variable. Apparently you cannot use the "picture" variable without "link", when you do this and you try to post the status as Unpublished, it will fail with an unknown error. However, for some reason, if published = true, it will work with picture and post an image without a link.

Answer (score -1):

```
["\/11111111111111\/feed", "POST", {
    "access_token": "xxxxxx",
    "message": "Test message",
    "picture": "http://
working.picture.path.com/pic.jpg",
    "published": false,
    "scheduled_publish_time":
1401406920
}]
```