# Facebook php schedule post - error unexpected exception

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a script for posting to managed pages which works unless i try and schedule the post. It fails on

```
Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later. [type] => OAuthException [code] => 2 ) )
```

I came across this [Facebook Graph API error when posting scheduled post on Business page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597793/facebook-graph-api-error-when-posting-scheduled-post-on-business-page) stating it could be a issue with the "link" but not specifying which link. But i tried all of them but still getting the same errors.

Also on a side question....do page access tokens expire? There seems to be some confusion over these.

```
    foreach($_POST['fb'] as $key=>$code){

    $facebookpage= $key;
    $facebookaccesstoken= $code;

    $newfacebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $appId,
        'secret' => $appSecret
        )); 

$time= time();
$newtime= $time +13600;

$attachment=array(
    'access_token'=> $facebookaccesstoken,
    'published' => false,
    'scheduled_publish_time'=> $newtime,
    'message'=> "new sasa posting me!",//user message
    'name'=> 'Anyone sasa interested in this? Check out my advert!',//title
    'link'=> 'http://testserverdavideec.mx.nf/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/user53734efe383247.67413395boats.jpg', // link to advert
    'description'=> 'myadvert asa brings the milkshakes',//inner ad
    'picture'=>'http://testserverdavideec.mx.nf/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/user53734efe383247.67413395boats.jpg',//picture url if empty= site logo
    'actions'=>array(array(
        'name'=>'dshjs',
        'link'=>'http://testserverdavideec.mx.nf/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/user53734efe383247.67413395boats.jpg'
    ))
);
$post_url='/'.$facebookpage.'/feed';

try{
    $result=$newfacebook->api($post_url,'POST',$attachment);
    echo '<h1> result=</h1>';    var_dump($result);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
print_r($e);
} 



}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed#publish) it's **NOT SUPPORTED** to use **published** with **actions** field. So you can use either scheduled_publish_time or actions but both won't go.

I hope it helps.